# `include` statement in `for` loop does not work

Tags: nunjucks

```
// item.html
test

// main.html
{% for i in range(1, 4) %}
abc
{% include "item.html" %}
def
{% endfor %}
{% include "item.html" %}
```

The output is:
`abcabcabctest` (three times `abc` and one time `test`). It means that for some reason include statement in loop does not work and also anything after the statement, but still inside loop, is not rendered either. However include outside of loop does work. This is almost same as example from docs so I have no idea what might be wrong with this code.

Using nunjucks v3.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it looks like everything is fine.

```
// app.js
var nunjucks  = require("nunjucks");
var env = nunjucks.configure();
var res = env.render("template.html");
console.log(res);

// template.html
{% for i in range(1, 3) %}
    {% include "partial"+ i + ".html" %}
{% endfor %}
{% include "partial1.html" %}

// partial1.html
AAA

// partail2.html
BBB
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by changing the web loader to synchronous:

```
this._nunjucksEnvironment = new nunjucks.Environment(
  new nunjucks.WebLoader(this.file(""), { async: false }),
  {
    trimBlocks: true,
    lstripBlocks: true
  }
);
```